# Dynamically Positioned Flex Components

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, layout

I have a requirement on my current project (a Flex app which will be run in Flash player) to display an arbitrary subset of the components on a form while hiding all the other components based on certain aspects of the application state.  There are about a dozen different text boxes and drop downs, but some become irrelevant based on previously entered user data and we don't want to display those when we get to this particular form.  Every time this form is displayed I could need to show any one of the many permutations of these components.

I'm trying to decide what the best way to approach this problem is.  Should I create a Canvas (or other container) with all of the needed controls on it and then just set visible = false on the ones I don't need?  The problem then becomes making sure the layout looks decent.  I don't want there to be gaps where the hidden controls would have been.

The other option I've thought about is just having a mechanism that could dynamically instantiate the TextInput or CheckBox etc. component and then call container.addChild(control) in order to build up the components and not have to worry about the gap issue.

This seems like a problem that has an idiomatic solution in flex, but I don't know what it is.  Neither of these ideas seem great so I'm wondering if anyone else has a better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is a good solution or not, but when I was in exactly the same situation, I did basically your first method.  Set `visible = false` and also set `includeInLayout = false` to prevent those "gaps" you were talking about.  It's a very simple solution, very easy and quick to implement... perhaps someone else knows of something more idiomatic though.

Comment: It is an OK solution for simple GUI layouts. It isn't very scalable though and cannot cope with transitions (collapsible regions etc). I'd definitely recommend learning the "proper" way through the use of states.

Comment: Having said that, the difference in our rep scores suggest that a number of silent observers disagree with me. Perhaps they'd like to speak up? :)

Answer (score 5):

The best practice way to do it is to use states. For example:

```
<mx:states>
    <mx:State name="State1">
        <mx:AddChild position="lastChild">
            <components.../>
        </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>
    <mx:State name="State2">
        <mx:AddChild position="lastChild">
            <mx:Canvas.../>
        </mx:AddChild>
        <mx:AddChild position="lastChild">
            <mx:VBox.../>
        </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>
</mx:states>
```

Then within your code, you call this.currentState = "State1" to enable the first state etc. Using states, you can selectively show and hide components.

I recommend googling for flex states tutorials and trying some out to get a proper idea of how states work.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I could end up needing to display any combination of about a dozen components.  If I understand view states correctly that would mean I would need a distinct state for every possible combination of controls which would be a lot.

Comment: Without knowing more details about your particular situation, it is difficult to say whether that would be a problem or not. Don't forget that states can be nested, so activating a child state activates controls associated with the parent state too. cont...

Comment: Also will 12 states be any more complex than the code needed to control which components are hidden/ shown for 12 user combinations?

Comment: I just updated the question.  The first paragraph should give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do now.

I don't think 12 states would be more complex, but I'm still not convinced I could do it with only 12 states even if they were nested.  Only 1 state can be active at at time right?

Comment: Every container component can have a state. So if your buttons and drop downs can be logically grouped onto canvases oe whatever, then each canvas can have a state.

Answer (score 0):

If states won't do, check out articles that explain the components life cycle.

If you create a class that extends a flex component like Canvas, you will define all components in a function that override createChildren. You will revisit the layout in another function that override updateDisplayList

- [Flex Component Life Cycle](https://web.archive.org/web/20080911223134/http://flexcomps.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/flex-component-life-cycle/) @flexcomps
- [Component Class - Part Three](https://web.archive.org/web/20090308034358/http://weblogs.macromedia.com:80/pent/archives/2007/10/component_class_2.html) @PeterEnt
- [Flex component lifecyle](http://guavus.wordpress.com/2008/09/15/flex-component-lifecycle/) @guavus
- [Understanding Custom Flex Component Development](http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/?p=21) @billWhite